# react native google sign in api not working

Tags: android, api, react-native, google-signin

My _signIn() function is not working when i click on the GoogleSigninButton component. I want the google credentials screen to pop up on clicking the button

This is my index.android.js

```
    import {GoogleSignin, GoogleSigninButton} from 'react-native-google-signin';

class xyz extends Component {
  _signIn () {
    GoogleSignin.signIn()
.then((user) => {
  console.log(user);
  this.setState({user: user});
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.log('WRONG SIGNIN', err);
})
.done();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React Native!
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          To get started, edit index.android.js
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          Shake or press menu button for dev menu
        </Text>
        <GoogleSigninButton
    style={{width: 48, height: 48}}
    size={GoogleSigninButton.Size.Icon}
    color={GoogleSigninButton.Color.Dark}
    onPress={this._signIn.bind(this)}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

build.gradle file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
```

settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'xyz'

include ':app'
include ':react-native-google-signin', ':app'
project(':react-native-google-signin').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-google-signin/android')
```

app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"]
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xyz"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile project(":react-native-google-signin")
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
  from configurations.compile
  into 'libs'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: you find the solution?

Answer (score 2):

try getting your sha1:

```
keytool -exportcert -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -list -v
```

then go to your google api console be sure that correct sha1 is registered on Android client for com.yourproject. somehow keytool may be changed (I am not sure maybe due to upgrating sdk buid tool etc.), and you need to match it on google api console. this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Google has released a new signing service in the Play Store, In the publish console Google will sign your app with their keystore. After signing, it will give you a new SHA which you have to add in your firebase account. See the image for the better understanding

[image: image showing where to update app signing]

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `GoogleSignin.configure({YOUR_CONFIG_DATA})` first. 
**configure** method creates new `_apiClient` object which is used in **signIn** method. (in `android/src/main/java/co/apptailor/googlesignin/RNGoogleSigninModule.java`)

Answer (score 0):

Mention your webclient id in useEffect() like this -
your webclinet ID will be in google-services.json

```
    useEffect(()=>{
            GoogleSignin.configure({
            webClientId: '<Web Clinet ID>',
          }); 
            },[]);
```

For webclient ID goto google-services.json = >

```
 "oauth_client": [
        {
          "client_id": "<This is what you want>",
          "client_type": 1,
          "android_info": {
            "package_name": "BlaBlaBla",
            "certificate_hash": "BlaBlaBla"
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Button**

```
  <View style={{ alignItems: 'center', flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-evenly' }}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={{
          width: scale(50),
          height: verticalScale(50),
          backgroundColor: '#eee',
          elevation: scale(5),
          borderRadius: scale(40),
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
        }}
          onPress={() => _singnIn()}
        >
          <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-evenly' }}>
            <Image source={require("../Image/google.png")} style={{ width: scale(30), height: scale(30) }} />
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
```

**_singnIn()**

```
  const _singnIn = async () => {
    GoogleSignin.configure({
      scopes: [],
      webClientId: 'webClicentID',
      offlineAccess: true,
    });

    try {
      await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices();
      const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
      console.log("UserInfo", userInfo.user)
      console.log("User Name", userInfo.user.name)
     
      } catch {
        console.log(error)
      }
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      if (error.code === statusCodes.SIGN_IN_CANCELLED) {
        console.log('user cancelled the login');
      } else if (error.code === statusCodes.IN_PROGRESS) {
        console.log('is in progress already');
      } else if (error.code === statusCodes.PLAY_SERVICES_NOT_AVAILABLE) {
        console.log('play services not avaliable or outdata');
      } else {
        //some other error
      }
    }
  };
```

Maybe this will help you!!